# Haskell Safe IO

Tags: haskell, types, io, io-monad

I am attempting to write a simple function to safely read a file (if it exists) and do nothing if the file does not exist:

```
safeRead :: String -> IO ()
safeRead path = readFile path `catch` handleExists
  where handleExists e
          | isDoesNotExistError e = return ()
          | otherwise = throwIO e
```

This fails at compile time with

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘()’
Expected type: IO ()
  Actual type: IO String
In the first argument of ‘catch’, namely ‘readFile path’
In the expression: readFile path `catch` handleExists
```

This makes sense since `:t readFile` is `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String`. e.g a function that returns `IO String` (and `IO String` is not the same as `IO ()`)

Changing the signature to `String -> IO String`

```
Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: IOError -> IO String
  Actual type: IOError -> IO ()
In the second argument of ‘catch’, namely ‘handleExists’
In the expression: readFile path `catch` handleExists
```

Which also makes sense since handleExists has type `IO ()`

To save everyone lookup, catch is imported with:
`import Control.Exception`
 the signature of catch is:
`catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a`

My real question is, how can I write this kind of error safe, flexible code in Haskell? More specifically what would be the change I would have to make to this function to have it handle both a success case and a failure case?

Comment: your code compiles for me making `isDoesNotexistError` always return true, so the problem may be in the otherwise part?

Comment: yep, just checked, throwIO is returning an `IO a`, not `IO ()`

Comment: to me it seems that the signature you are looking for is `String -> IO (Maybe String)`

Comment: check this: http://goo.gl/XI2N5y
it compiles, change your signature to `String -> IO a`, im just testing, not sure if it is ok

Comment: @DanielSanchez What are you on about? `IO a` unifies with `IO ()` just fine, and the code in the link you posted doesn't compile at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to figure out what you want your function to actually do.

If it successfully reads the file, you want it to return the contents as a string.

If it fails, what do you actually want it to do? Return an empty string or some other fallback content? Then you can just change the `return ()` to `return ""` in the first case of `handleExists`.

But if you want to indicate the error in the return type, then you need to return a different type than just `String`. As Carsten said, you can return a `Maybe String` and give `Just theString` for success and `Nothing` for error. Or you could return an `Either` if you want some error message instead.

I feel that for this particular function, `Maybe String` makes the most sense, since you only catch non-presence of the file and rethrow other errors. Then your code needs to look like this:

```
safeRead :: String -> IO (Maybe String)
safeRead path = (fmap Just $ readFile path) `catch` handleExists
  where
    handleExists :: IOException -> IO (Maybe String)
    handleExists e
      | isDoesNotExistError e = return Nothing
      | otherwise = throwIO e
```

Here we wrap the result of `readFile` in a `Just` to fulfill the type requirement, and in the error case return `Nothing` instead of unit.

Comment: I don't think it will work this way - IMO you have to help out the compiler by giving the `Exception` instance like this: `handleExists :: IOException -> IO (Maybe String) ...` ... yep - Haskell is complaining on when I try yours ;) - I allowed myself to change yours into a working condition - just roll back if you don't like it

Comment: of course you probably won't need this if `isDooesNotExistError` has the right signature ... I was lazy and just did `isDoesNotExistError = undefined` ;)

Comment: @Carsten I have no idea, I didn't actually compile it. `isDoesNotExistError` has the right signature, so I would assume it compiles without the signature, but it doesn't hurt either.